# select2 initializes but unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am working with select2.  I have serveral dropdowns on a page with the class `.select2` and I initialize all of them as select2 with the call `$('.select2').select2();` This has worked great for every drop down except for one and it is really strange.  When I inspect the element it looks like everything is created using the call above but I am unable to click the element to make it drop down.  Below is the code and some pictures:

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-12">Builder <small style="font-size: 55%;">(only NC)</small></label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select class="form-control select2" id="builder" name="builder">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <?php 
        for ($i=0;$i<$drpBuilderCount;$i++) {
          echo '<option value="'.$drpBuilderValue[$i].'">"'.$drpBuilderName[$i].'"</option>';
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

**Here is what the code looks like when inspected:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-12">Builder<small>(only NC)</small></label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="select2-container form-control select2" id="s2id_builder">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">  
        <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2"></span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
        <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
          <b role="presentation"></b>
        </span>
      </a>
      <label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
      <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2">
      <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
        <div class="select2-search">
          <label for="s2id_autogen2_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-2" id="s2id_autogen2_search" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-2">   </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="builder" name="builder" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">"Add New"</option>
      <option value="2">"Curt Moran"</option>
      <option value="3">"Redstone Homes"</option>
      <option value="4">"Roots Construction"</option>
      <option value="5">"BDR Custom Homes"</option>
      <option value="6">"Heartland Builders LLC"</option>
      <option value="7">"Engelsma Homes"</option>                    
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like it should from what I can tell but visually I see this:
[image]

As you can see there is no drop arrow to the right and clicking the element does nothing.

Here is an image of a select2 drop down that on the same page with the class `.select2` that is initializing properly:

[image]

I need the builder `<select>` to initialize just as all the other select tags are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this issue, it had to do with using a blank option tag.  select2 does not like a completely blank option tags like `<option value="0"></option>` or even `<option></option>` I needed to add a non-breaking space as the text in order to make the drop down fully initialize like this `<option value="0">&nbsp;</option>` now it initizies as expected and works great.

Hopefully, this helps someone else that runs into this situation.